# Rails + jquery auto complete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have following jquery code to acheive autocomplete functionality. Auto complete works find but i want to add delimiter with this, please guide me how to work on this,

delimiter should be ',' separated because field autosuggests with enmail id

thanks

> ```
> $('.userName').autocomplete({
>         minLength: 1,
>         source: '<%= getUser_path(:json) %>',
>         focus: function(event, ui) {      var i = this.id
>             $('#'+i).val(ui.item.user.email); 
>             return false;
>         },
>
>         select: function(event, ui) {         var i = this.id
>             $('#'+i).val(ui.item.user.email);
>             return false;
>         } 
>     })
>
>     .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
>         return $( "<li></li>" )
>             .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
>             .append( "<a>" + item.user.name + " " + item.user.email + "</a>" )
>             .appendTo( ul );
>     };
> ```